# How to create a rank or an index column based on more than one column?

Tags: python-3.x, python-polars

I have a a problem (a simple one i believe) which i can't get my head around.
I'm looking for a way to create a rank or an index column based on two columns in ascending order and partitioning by a specific column.

see example below

```py
data = {
          'id' : [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5] ,
          'month' : [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2] ,
          'sales' : [20.1, 34.7, 89.4, 932.65, 12.7, 65.2, 893.2, 89.2, 12.0, 12.25],         
          'sector' : ['sec1', 'sec1', 'sec1', 'sec1', 'sec1', 'sec2', 'sec2', 'sec2', 'sec2', 'sec2'],      
       }

pl.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to create a rank for every sector sorted by the ['id','month'] ascending for both.
so ideally, something among the lines of row_number() in sql.

I tried to first sort the dataframe by ascending order, i.e.,

```py
.sort(by=['month', 'id'], descending=[False, False])
```

and then something like this:

```py
.with_columns(pl.lit(1).cumsum().over('sector').alias('order_trade'))
```

but to no avail.
I also attempted some bunch of `groupby expressions`, and using the `rank method` but couldn't figure it out.

the result I'm looking for is a 'rank' column which is based off of on the month and id column, where both are in ascending order partitioned by the sector.

**Expected Output**

*i've edited the data input to make it a bit simpler to get my point across.*

it `sql` I'd do something like this:

```sql
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Sector ORDER BY month_number ASC, id ASC) AS 'rank'
```

thus, something like this.

| rank | id | month_number | sector | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | sec1 | 20.1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | sec1 | 34.7 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | sec1 | 89.4 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | sec1 | 932.65 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 | sec1 | 12.7 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | sec2 | 65.2 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | sec2 | 893.2 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | sec2 | 89.2 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | sec2 | 12.0 |
| 5 | 5 | 2 | sec2 | 12.25 |

Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: @jqurious, done.
I've also edited the data input to make it a bit simpler to understand. Thanks in advance for any input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've shuffled the order of your example.

```py
df = pl.from_repr("""
┌─────┬───────┬────────┬────────┐
│ id  ┆ month ┆ sales  ┆ sector │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ i64   ┆ f64    ┆ str    │
╞═════╪═══════╪════════╪════════╡
│ 2   ┆ 1     ┆ 34.7   ┆ sec1   │
│ 1   ┆ 1     ┆ 20.1   ┆ sec1   │
│ 3   ┆ 1     ┆ 89.4   ┆ sec1   │
│ 10  ┆ 2     ┆ 12.25  ┆ sec2   │
│ 5   ┆ 1     ┆ 12.7   ┆ sec1   │
│ 6   ┆ 2     ┆ 65.2   ┆ sec2   │
│ 4   ┆ 1     ┆ 932.65 ┆ sec1   │
│ 8   ┆ 2     ┆ 89.2   ┆ sec2   │
│ 9   ┆ 2     ┆ 12.0   ┆ sec2   │
│ 7   ┆ 2     ┆ 893.2  ┆ sec2   │
└─────┴───────┴────────┴────────┘
""")
```

It looks like you're after a ["dense rank"](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rank.html#polars.Expr.rank):

```py
df.with_columns(rank = pl.col("id").rank("dense").over("sector"))
```

```py
shape: (10, 5)
┌─────┬───────┬────────┬────────┬──────┐
│ id  ┆ month ┆ sales  ┆ sector ┆ rank │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64   ┆ f64    ┆ str    ┆ u32  │
╞═════╪═══════╪════════╪════════╪══════╡
│ 2   ┆ 1     ┆ 34.7   ┆ sec1   ┆ 2    │
│ 1   ┆ 1     ┆ 20.1   ┆ sec1   ┆ 1    │
│ 3   ┆ 1     ┆ 89.4   ┆ sec1   ┆ 3    │
│ 10  ┆ 2     ┆ 12.25  ┆ sec2   ┆ 5    │
│ 5   ┆ 1     ┆ 12.7   ┆ sec1   ┆ 5    │
│ 6   ┆ 2     ┆ 65.2   ┆ sec2   ┆ 1    │
│ 4   ┆ 1     ┆ 932.65 ┆ sec1   ┆ 4    │
│ 8   ┆ 2     ┆ 89.2   ┆ sec2   ┆ 3    │
│ 9   ┆ 2     ┆ 12.0   ┆ sec2   ┆ 4    │
│ 7   ┆ 2     ┆ 893.2  ┆ sec2   ┆ 2    │
└─────┴───────┴────────┴────────┴──────┘
```

Comment: thanks! seems to do the trick. one question though. say, the `id` column starts over again every month. how would you account for it, when creating a `rank/row_number` using polars? i.e., both [id, month] are needed for creating the `rank` column.

Comment: Sounds like: `pl.struct("id", "month").rank("dense").over("sector")` - if you want to edit your example to include this scenario I can update the answer.

Comment: just edited the data to fit the question.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for `pl.struct("id", "month").rank("dense").over("sector")` - however it's difficult to tell because that generates the same result as `pl.col("id").rank` for the example given. (as does the SQL)

Comment: the struct.rank expression works like a charm!